# Беспорядок со знаками препинания в окне старта конкурса

Tags: дефект, предложение, локализация, конкурс

Взгляните на окно старта конкурса:

[image: Скриншот дефекта]

Мне кажется, с текстом есть некоторые проблемы в плане пунктуации:

- Слово "подробнее" должно быть в скобках.
- Между троеточием и "подробнее" не должно быть пробела.
- У предложения нет точки. А троеточие относится к "подробнее".

Предлагаю такой вариант:

> Вы можете объявить не более 3 конкурсов одновременно ([подробнее](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/bounty)).

**UPD**:
В комментариях @αλεχολυτ написал, что проблему надо начинать с оригинала. Начал конкурс на [баг-репорте на MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/260140/1346379), чтобы хоть какое-то внимание привлечь к этому. Ждём.

**UDP2**:
конкурс на 50 баллов репутации не спас положение. Начинаю конкурс на 100 баллов репутации...

Comment: Проблему надо начинать решать с [оригинального баннера](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sonxn.png). Даже [репорт](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/260140/339911) есть 8-летней давности.